# Merge is not updating the records

Tags: database, oracle, merge

I am trying to create current and previous record for my `scdthree_dim_placement` table using MERGE.

When I try to update `plct_desc` in `clean_placement`table `previous_plct_desc` in `scdthree_dim_placement` shows nothing and `current_plct_desc` column is also not working properly .

There are no errors shown when I run the script. I am a beginner so it will be a great help if someone could tell me what i am doing wrong.

```
drop table scdthree_dim_placement;
create table scdthree_dim_placement
(
scdplacement_id number(8),
placement_key number (8),
current_plct_desc varchar2(50),
previous_plct_desc varchar2(50),
plct_start_date date,
PRIMARY KEY (scdplacement_id)
);
drop sequence plctscd_seq;
CREATE SEQUENCE plctscd_seq START WITH 1;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER plct_bir
BEFORE INSERT ON scdthree_dim_placement
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT plctscd_seq.NEXTVAL
  INTO   :new.scdplacement_id
  FROM   dual;
END;
/
```

Here is my MERGE statement:

```
merge into scdthree_dim_placement a 
    using clean_placement  b 
    on (a.PLACEMENT_KEY=b.PLACEMENT_ID)
WHEN matched THEN
    UPDATE SET
        a.current_plct_desc = b.plct_desc,
        a.previous_plct_desc = a.current_plct_desc,
        a.plct_start_date = b.plct_start_date
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (
        a.placement_key,
        a.current_plct_desc,
        a.plct_start_date
    )
    VALUES(
        b.placement_id,
        b.plct_desc,
        b.plct_start_date
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no problem with syntax except `two blank lines` between the line with `a.plct_start_date=b.plct_start_date` and the line with `WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN` clauses, remove those lines.

There may occur problem with primary key violation provided any coincidence occurs for values coming from the sequence and values of `scdplacement_id`(which has primary key constraint).

Answer (score 0):

```
--Code looks fine. Just Remove Extra Space

drop table scdthree_dim_placement;
create table scdthree_dim_placement
(
scdplacement_id number(8),
placement_key number (8),
current_plct_desc varchar2(50),
previous_plct_desc varchar2(50),
plct_start_date date,
PRIMARY KEY (scdplacement_id)
);
drop sequence plctscd_seq;
CREATE SEQUENCE plctscd_seq START WITH 1;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER plct_bir
BEFORE INSERT ON scdthree_dim_placement
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT plctscd_seq.NEXTVAL
  INTO   :new.scdplacement_id
  FROM   dual;
END;
/

merge into scdthree_dim_placement a using clean_placement  b on
       (a.PLACEMENT_KEY=b.PLACEMENT_ID)
WHEN matched
THEN
 UPDATE SET
a.current_plct_desc=b.plct_desc,
a.previous_plct_desc=a.current_plct_desc,
a.plct_start_date=b.plct_start_date
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (
a.placement_key,
a.current_plct_desc,
a.plct_start_date
)
VALUES(
b.placement_id,
b.plct_desc,
b.plct_start_date
);
```